# Merge two streams in RxJs without replay

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have stripped down my problem to this simple example.

```
var button1Click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('button1'),'click')
                      .map(function(){
                        console.log('Map:all');
                        return "all"
                      })

var odd$ = button1Click$.filter(function(){
   return (Date.now() %2 === 1);
})
.map(function(){
      console.log('Map:odd');
       return "odd"
     })



var combined$ = button1Click$.merge(odd$);
combined$.subscribe(function(ev){
  console.log(ev);
});
```

[Demo: https://jsbin.com/diredeb/edit?js,console,output](https://jsbin.com/diredeb/edit?js,console,output)

I have created a stream of clicks and a stream of odd clicks(based on current time) by filtering clicks stream.
Now I want a single stream, which receives both events 'all' and 'odd'.
So I am merging these two stream with `merge`. Problem is with `merge`, `map` defined in `button1Click$` is getting invoked twice. Suppose If I create another stream named `even$` and merge it too, `map` is getting invoked thrice. Check the demo.

How can I merge the streams so that `map` (defined for `button1Click$`) gets invoked only once per click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `share` the `button1Clicked$`:

```
var button1Click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('button1'),'click')
                  .map(function(){
                    console.log('Map:all');
                    return "all"
                  })
                  .share();
```

Comment: `.share()` shares the stream between multiple subscribers, so the stream itself is always just executes once, but all subscribers will receive the emitted data. - here is a link to (the old) docs, that basically explain exactly your very issue: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md